# Detect names using pocketsphinx

Tags: android, names, pocketsphinx

I am trying to recognize a person name using pocketsphinx. I created a keyphrase list that contains a list of names with a threshold frequency (eg : ABC /1.0/).I passed this file as input to addKeywordSearch() function. Still its failed to listen to the keyword. Am I missing anything?

Is it necessary that name should be present in the dict file? If it so is it possible to do a recognition without dict?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary that name should be present in the dict file?

Yes

> If it so is it possible to do a recognition without dict?

No